# Square In Person Payment changed documentation intent fields, would that impact in future?

Tags: square, square-connect

I noticed that documentation for Sqaure In Person Payments have changed the intent fields from `S.com.squareup.register.WEB_CALLBACK_URI` to `S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI`. I had implemented the older one almost 2 to 3 months back.

Now I followed the documentation again, I see the difference. Anyhow I have tested In Person Payments yesterday, it was working fine though. I just want to be sure if this will effect or I need to change the intent fields?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest intent string you pasted in the comments, the callback URI is https://b14a98‌​69.ngrok.io/baskets/‌​charge_with_square . I checked, and this callback URI doesn't exist in our systems, however I found other URIs that end in /baskets/‌​charge_with_square . So the solution is very likely for you to add https://b14a98‌​69.ngrok.io/baskets/‌​charge_with_square to the list of callback URIs that are already registered in the developer portal

[image: web callbacks]

Answer (score 0):

You should change so that you can take advantage of future features. Read more on [Square's Developer Blog](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/squares-register-api-is-now-point-of-sale-api-a9956032c32a)

Comment: I did change the intent as 
`intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.browser_fallback_url=#{call_back_url};S.S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=#{call_back_url};S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID=#{SQUARE_CLIENT_ID};S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0;i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT={{PAYABLE_AMOUNT}};S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=#{CURRENCY_CODE};S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CASH;S.com.squareup.pos.NOTE={{COMMENTS}};end`

Comment: I simply replaced the `register` with `pos` and VERSION from `1.3` to `2.0` and It generates the following error

`The WEB_VALLBACK_URI parameter must be set for the Web API request`

I can't see any help in the documentation, Though it's working fine with previous version of firing intent.

Comment: Are you sure your callback URI is getting filled in? Can you print it after your variables are filled in? It seems you use `#{}` and `{{}}` in your template.

Comment: `intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.browser_fallback_url=https://order.lvh.me/baskets/charge_with_square;S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=https://order.lvh.me/baskets/charge_with_square;S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID=CLIENT_ID;S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0;i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT=100;S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=USD;S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD;S.com.squareup.pos.REQUEST_METADATA=abc;end`

Here is the intent after proper rendering.

Comment: well #{} and {{}} won't be an issue because they are rendering ruby code and that is rendering fine. After removing that tags even, i am getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pasting it again, Just i want to show you the same call back url.
`intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.browser_fallback_url=https://b14a9869.ngrok.io/baskets/charge_with_square;S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=https://b14a9869.ngrok.io/baskets/charge_with_square;S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID=CLIENT_ID;S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0;i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT=100;S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=USD;S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD;S.com.squareup.pos.REQUEST_METADATA=abc;end`

Comment: @ZainbSallahuddin

1) Is your actual client ID being interpolated?  S‌​.com.squareup.pos.CL‌​IENT_ID=CLIENT_ID should actually be S‌​.com.squareup.pos.CL‌​IENT_ID=(your client id obtained from the developer portal), but I can understand if you deliberately chose to omit your actual client id here.

2) what version of Square POS do you have installed?  The namespace change takes effect as of version 4.64 and above.

Comment: Yes! i had written CLIENT_ID intentionally, Please assume it's correct.
I have Square POS installed with version 4.66

Comment: @jrod have this issue figured out yet? What exactly am i missing?